# Shell script calling a java executable and catching exception

Tags: java, shell, unix, java-8

We have a java executable file that can be run from command line like:

```
>>java -jar something.jar
```

This will be called by a shell script. How can we make the shell script detect if the executable jar has thrown an exception? lets say we want it to return "true" if the executable jar finished with no exception and "false" if it threw an exception. Is this possible?

Comment: Just because the java program throws an exception does not mean that the program has finished unless you will `exit` at that time.  If so change the value of the `System.exit`

Comment: yeah we figured that out too. problem is how to catch that from shell script

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Do you really mean thrown an exception or do you mean shown an exception, but captured it? Can you show a sample program which throws an exception without termination?

Comment: Are we talking about catched Exceptions? Are we talking about silently catched exceptions, too?

Comment: Based upon the OP's answer to my comment, the OP does not really care about Exceptions but just about the `exit-code` hence @userunknown answer about how to handle the exit code is correct.  Not at all Java specific

Answer (score 1):

I would try as always. If the call is the last command in the script, this is what the script does anyhow. Else capture the return value `$?`.

```
   java -jar something.jar 
   result=$?

   if [[ $result ]] ; then ... ; fi
   # ...
   exit $result
```

However, I wouldn't call this "catching the exception with the script", since you are normally in the program which caused the exception and decide, where to catch it, so that you can either might handle it gracefully, correct, retry or do some cleanup before exit. That's what you can do inside of your script to some extend too, and should do it, maybe even restart the program with different data or environment, so it's arguable.

Answer (score -1):

All exceptions will be in STDERR. There are at least 2 option: you could route it to regular output, grep for Exception:

```
java -jar something.jar 2>&1 | grep Exception
```

or log to file

```
java -jar something.jar 2>something.log
cat something.log | grep Exception
```

If you are interested in exit code, it will print it

```
java -jar something.jar; echo $?
```

You could add `| sort -u` to display only unique exceptions or `| wc -l` to count all exceptions.